# Converting from Google.Gdata.Calendar to Google.Apis.Calendar v3

Tags: google-calendar-api

How do I replace the code -

```
CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
query.Uri = new  Uri(String.Format("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{0}/allcalendars/full", googleAccount));
 CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed)service.Query(query);
```

using the Google.Apis.Calendar v3 interface?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a list operation on the CalendarList collection, see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

There is a java example at the bottom in the examples section.